# What constitutes activity on a question?

Tags: support

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78592/how-to-implement-fire-detector-smoketemperature-for-an-electronics-project) is a perfect example. Nothing has been added or edited. What caused it to get bumped?

Comment: As a non-moderator you can often spot deleted answers because it'll show the person who modified it last but you'll see on their profile no answered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [What does "inactive" mean exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164294/what-does-inactive-mean-exactly) which semi-describes inactivity for the Archeologist tag (editing 6 month old inactive questions), activity is any new answers, or edits to the question or answers. Tag edits count for activity, but not for the badge.

That specific question had someone add an answer that should have been a new question. That answer was deleted accordingly.

And it's not just mods who can see that, but anyone that has gained the "Access to Moderation Tools" https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools privilege at 10k rep. (Frankly, I wish there was a way to turn viewing deleted answers off, they are annoying).

And as W5V0, unanswered/upvoted questions get bumped by the system to give them more attention.

Answer (score 5):

While it wasn't true it *this* case, the system will randomly bump questions that have 0 upvoted answers.

Answer (score 3):

A new answers was added and deleted, you can not see it, but there was activity.